# How to test a RetrofitSpiceRequest?

Tags: android, retrofit, robospice

I'm trying to unit test a `RetrofitSpiceRequest` using Square's `MockWebServer`. The problem is that in the current `RoboSpice` implementation, the `server url` is passed through a subclass method, which makes it difficult, if not impossible, to inject a different base url in runtime as the services are initialized by the `SpiceManager` without parameters.

(RetrofitSpiceService)

```
protected RestAdapter.Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
    return new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(getServerUrl()).setConverter(getConverter());
}
```

Currently, I'm working around this by changing the base url static field in the unit test, which is far from ideal.

Is there a better solution?